# QSPI NOR Flash Memory wear

Tags: embedded, firmware, flash-memory

I am implementing QSPI data logging in my firmware. My log size is 16B and I have 8 MB of storage, assuming I cycle through all my sectors to get even wear on the flash chip is there anything else I need to be concerned about?

My goal is a 10 year life expectancy, I have done a calculation to see how frequently I can write per hour and I am concerned I am misunderstanding because my calculations show I can write very frequently.

8 MB / 16 B = (524k logs per storage) * (100k erase cycles) = (524k * 100k) logs per flash chip life

(524k * 100k) / (10years * 365days * 24 hours) = 600k logs per hour

Chip: https://media-www.micron.com/-/media/client/global/documents/products/data-sheet/nor-flash/serial-nor/mt25q/die-rev-a/mt25q_qljs_u_256_aba_0.pdf?rev=594079234c1b496496b062c21ce162d6

Edit: My sector size is 4 KB so I guess I am concerned if 256 writes before an erase will cause additional ware that I am not considering? ( 4 KB / 16 bytes = 256 writes)

Comment: Why do your numbers surprise you?  That seems reasonable given your wear friendly write pattern.  Personally I'd use that as an opportunity to partition the flash and use a smaller amount for logging.  You could usefully use it for other purposes such as configuration, or even a filesystem.

Comment: This is for a device that is already deployed in field, its a 32MB chip with about 20 MB unused. My sector size is 4 KB so I guess I am concerned if 256 writes before an erase will cause additional ware that I am not considering ( 4 KB / 16 bytes = 256 writes)

Comment: The endurance is per bit, so a write to one byte will not affect an adjacent byte - or even bit for that matter.  In fact it is the transition from 1 to 0 followed by an erase that wears, so storing a 1 bit is free. Anyhow this is clearly a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ rather than SO.

Comment: Thanks for response, first time posting. Will use other forum for now on.

Comment: That is not what I meant - use this forum for software development issues (including embedded software), use Electronics StackExchange for hardware issues - like this one.  If it is both software and hardware, pick whichever is appropriate based on balance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can write very frequently, in case you consider one write per hour to be frequent.

> Edit: My sector size is 4 KB so I guess I am concerned if 256 writes before an erase will cause additional ware that I am not considering? ( 4 KB / 16 bytes = 256 writes)

If you are willing to sacrifice the whole 8Mb, then this improves the situation and gives you twice the amount of write cycles, assuming you only erase one of the sectors once the other one is full.

```
1024*1024*4 / 16 = 262k sector writes before erase
262k*2 = 524k writes in total before both sectors have been erased
524k*100k = 52.4*10^9 hours.
```

This assuming that 16 times 0xFF (value of erased memory) cannot be valid data.

Answer (score 0):

Will repeated writes to a 4K sector, assuming you're not writing the same words twice cause additional wear? No.

Is there a scenario where you'd see additional wear - yes, some Flash parts have limitations on how many times you could program the same word (for example, you're gradually settings bits to 0 to track something going on) before a write would fail even though the word is still fine and will work correctly once erased. A quick read of the program instructions does not indicate this particular Flash part has such a limitation.